# Java newbie trying to figure out NullPointerException and

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm doing the iTunes U Stanford CS106a course in Java and am loving it but am tearing my hear out over this Name Surfer program.

When I use this code

```
public NameSurferEntry(String line) {
  int endOfName = line.indexOf(" ");
  name = line.substring(0,endOfName);
  String newLine = line.substring(endOfName+1);
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(newLine);

  if (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    name = tokenizer.nextToken();
  }

  for (int i = 0; tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
  }
}
```

I get a Suspended/NullPointerException on the second line (int endOfName, etc.) that says "NameSurferEntry.(String) line: 16".

If I try to do it this way:

```
public NameSurferEntry(String line) {
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
  name = tokenizer.nextToken();

  for (int i = 0; tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
  }
}
```

I get a Suspended/NullPointerException with the message "StringTokenizer.(String, String, boolean) line: 182" followed by "Source not found."

Does anybody have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help.

NameSurferEntry is actually called by another class that provides a value for `null`.  But after reading your suggestions I've declared `line` as an ivar but initialized it in the body of NameSurferEntry, and that fixes it.  (Before I was both declaring and initializing `line` as an ivar.  I don't understand why the place I initialize it makes a difference, but there it is.)

The next error isn't until line 48!  So you may hear from me again very soon....  On my way to see whether I can figure it out on my own.  Thanks again.

**WHOOPS**

Not so fast.

When I initialize `line` to an actual String in the body of NameSurferEntry, everything works out fine.

The problem is that NameSurferEntry is called by another method:

```
public NameSurferDataBase(String filename) {
  try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    while (true) {
      String blah = br.readLine();

      if (blah == null) {
        break;
      }

      NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry(blah);
      hmap.put(entry.getName(), entry);
    }
    br.close();
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);           
  }
}
```

(This method is in turn called by another method that gives it an actual file for `filename`, so we're okay there.)

But if I'm passing the parameter `blah` to `NameSurferEntry`, and `NameSurferEntry` then initializes its parameter, then I've lost `blah`, right?  My impulse is then to initialize `line` as an ivar outside of the method, but then I get the `NullPointerException` message again and I'm back where I started.  Argh!

Thoughts?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Your last posted code ensures that the `NameSurferEntry` constructor is called with non-null values only. So everything should be fine... Please reduce your wall of text and make clear what your question really is. When it is not the original question then leave this here as it is and ask another question.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm new to StackOverflow and am still figuring out how it works.  I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `line` argument is null. That's why you are getting a `NullPointerException` while trying to operate on `line` (using `indexOf` and `StringTokenizer` on `line` will raise a `NullPointerException` if `line` is null- it has nothing to operate on).

Comment: Well, NameSurferEntry is called by another class, which looks like this:

Comment: Made an update--not sure how this works, whether you get notified.  But basically the answer is that you guys helped me fix it.  Now on to the next error, which isn't until line 48!

Comment: @JoelDerfner Glad to have helped you! :) I suggest opening another question for your next error. SO usually addresses one question per post, so you should open another post for your next question.

Comment: Don't know whether you get notified of updates, but I realized my fix didn't actually fix it.  The good news is that I figured out my next error myself, but now I'm back on this one.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well--I fixed it (at least as of now) by putting the NameSurferEntry code inside an if (line!=null) statement.  On to the error after my next one....

Comment: @JoelDerfner Good to hear that you fixed it! In SO, when you put a comment to an answer or question, the asker or answerer get notified.

Answer (score 2):

The `line` variable that you give your constructor as argument is `null`.

Make sure you input not `null` if you call `NameSurferEntry` constructor.